# how to change the directory of docker

Tags: docker

-- I installed docker on my debian 8

-- I pulled `docker-handbrake` from https://github.com/jlesage/docker-handbrake

`docker pull jlesage/handbrake`
and installed it

-- I had 2 drives,

the first one is my OS drive which mounted on `/`

the  second one is my storage drive which mounted on `/srv`

so the thing I want to do is run handbrake docker directories on `/srv` with the following command

```
    --name=handbrake \
    -p 5800:5800 \
    -v /docker/appdata/handbrake:/config:rw \
    -v /srv:ro \
    -v /srv/HandBrake/watch:/watch:rw \
    -v /srv/HandBrake/output:/output:rw \
    jlesage/handbrake
```

but i got this error :
`docker: Error response from daemon: invalid bind mount spec "/srv:ro": invalid volume specification: '/srv:ro'.
See 'docker run --help'.`

Comment: Whats `/srv:ro` supposed to do? Did you mean `/srv:/srv:ro`?

Answer (score 1):

I can do something like this.

```
--name=handbrake \
    -p 5800:5800 \
    -v /docker/appdata/handbrake:/config:rw \
    -v /srv:/storage:ro \
    -v /srv/HandBrake/watch:/watch:rw \
    -v /srv/HandBrake/output:/output:rw \
    jlesage/handbrake
```

Or

```
--name=handbrake \
    -p 5800:5800 \
    -v /docker/appdata/handbrake:/config:rw \
    -v /:/storage:ro \
    -v /srv/HandBrake/watch:/watch:rw \
    -v /srv/HandBrake/output:/output:rw \
    jlesage/handbrake
```

Note: Make sure you are not changing container directory which /storage:ro . Just change your host directory or path.